# Google Maps openInfoWindowHTML array problem

Tags: google-maps, multidimensional-array

Could someone please help explain why I can't get this to work? I properly generates all the locations, however, it doesn't generate the info boxes. Why is this and can someone help me with it?

```
            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
            map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
            map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(47.6062, -122.3321), 8);
            var wa_locations = new Array(new Array("Seattle", "47.6062", "-122.3321", "###-###-####", "###-###-####"),
                                         new Array("Bellevue", "47.6104", "-122.2007", "###-###-####", "###-###-####"),
                                         new Array("Tacoma", "47.2529", "-122.4443", "###-###-####", "###-###-####"),
                                         new Array("Everett", "47.9790", "-122.2021", "###-###-####", "###-###-####"));
            for(var i = 0; i < wa_locations.length; i++)
            {
                var point = new GLatLng(wa_locations[i][1], wa_locations[i][2]);
                map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point)); 
                GEvent.addListener(point, "click", function()
                {
                    point.openInfoWindowHtml("<b>" + wa_locations[i][0] + "</b><br/>Sales: " + wa_locations[i][3] +  "<br/>Helpdesk: " + wa_locations[i][4] +  "");
                });                     
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding a listener to your point instead of to your marker. Further, from your comment it appears you have a JavaScript closure issue. You can avoid the listener and the closure by using [bindInfoWindowHtml](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker.bindInfoWindowHtml). Here's the last part tweaked to use the marker and bindInfoWindowHtml:

```
        for(var i = 0; i < wa_locations.length; i++)
        {
            var point = new GLatLng(wa_locations[i][1], wa_locations[i][2]);
            var marker = new GMarker(point);
            marker.bindInfoWindowHtml("<b>" + wa_locations[i][0] + "</b><br/>Sales: " + wa_locations[i][3] +  "<br/>Helpdesk: " + wa_locations[i][4] +  "");
            map.addOverlay(marker); 
        }
```

Comment: So now it kicks back an error when I click on these object:
Message: 'wa_locations[...].0' is null or not an object

Comment: I tweaked my answer to remove the JavaScript closure and use bindInfoWindowHtml.